# Windows equivalent for "find . -name "*.zip" | xargs rm"

Tags: linux, windows-xp, command-line

I can do the following in Linux:

```
find . -name "*.zip" | xargs rm
```

What is its equivalent in Windows (XP, if it matters)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried

```
del /S /P *.zip
```

Comment: Just beat me by a 1 minute. (http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/recursively-delete-files-in-folders-and-sub-folders-using-command-prompt.html) offers help and recommends del /S command.

Answer (score 1):

1. My way: install Cygwin, `find . -name '*.zip' -delete`
2. User way: Find '*.zip'* in Total Commander, "feed to list box", select all, delete.